# How to skew a div and ensure that the width is always 50%?

Tags: css, skew

I'm struggling to skew a div like the image below... whereby the bottom and top always cover 50% of the screen width if that makes sense.

I have attached an image for more info

EDIT: this is a photoshop image and I'm trying to recreate this with CSS.

[image]

Comment: but it's 50% width. So be clear about *your* 50% --> show the result *you* want

Comment: I know, sorry - should have specified that this is a photoshop image... that's how bad it's gotten. This is the result I want

Comment: Is your question how to calculate the skewX value to make the result as wide as the window? That isn't very clear.

Comment: Yeah, so  I'd like to recreate the above image, but the blue section should always be 50% of the width at both the bottom and the top - even when the screen size changes... if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the use case, but you can recreate this using 2 `linear-gradient`. Each one will have a triangle shape and will cover half the container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top left, blue 50%,transparent 50.5%) left/50% 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue 50%,transparent 50.5%) right/50.5% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I never thought of using a gradient and instead was focussing on skewing a div. This is so much better. Thank you!

Comment: Just to let you know, I've applied a few variations of this and this is exactly what I needed.  thanks again!